# JSF h:dataTable creates single empty cell when no records

Tags: html, jsf, datatable

Is there any way to prevent an h:datatable from creating an empty row when the backing value is empty?
More specifically:
I have a collection of data to be displayed in 3 columns in an h:dataTable with column headers.  The thead always needs to be displayed, regardless of if there are elements in the list.  This works fine, but when no elements are in the list, a single, empty row/cell is created in the tbody.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Sample method from backing bean. For testing i've tried returning both null or an empty list.  Same result for both.

```
    public List<LocationsDecorator> getLocations() {
    return null;
}
```

JSF fragment:

```
<h:dataTable styleClass="locations" id="locations1"
    var="nearestLoc" value="#{confirmationBean.locations}">
    <h:column>
        <!-- column header -->
        <f:facet name="header">Address</f:facet>
        <!-- row record -->
            #{nearestLoc.adddress}
        </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <!-- column header -->
        <f:facet name="header">Distance</f:facet>
        <!-- row record -->
            #{nearestLoc.distance}
        </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <!-- column header -->
        <f:facet name="header">Hours of Operation</f:facet>
        <!-- row record -->
        <h:dataTable styleClass="locations" var="data"
            value="#{nearestLoc.hoursOfOperation}">
            <h:column>     
                #{data}
                </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>

    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

Resulting HTML(The "`<tr><td></td></tr>`" in the tbody is the problem):

```
<table id="contact:locations1" class="locations">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Distance</th>
<th scope="col">Hours of Operation</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot to describe why exactly it is a problem, so it's not possible to propose an answer which solves the problem.

Comment: It causes a problem when applying styling such as a border or bkgnd color to the table cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify a separate style for an empty table. E.g.

```
table.empty tbody td {
    border: 0;
}
```

And add it conditionally.

```
<h:dataTable ... styleClass="locations #{empty component.value ? 'empty' : ''}">
```

Comment: Can I find an example for this somewhere?

Comment: @sans: just create yourself based on the information provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid the column header disapearing if you instead wrap your method in an outputText tag

Example:

```
  <h:column>
    <!-- column header -->
    <f:facet name="header">Address</f:facet>
    <!-- row record -->
       <h:outputText value="#{nearestLoc.adddress}" />
    </h:column>
```

This way the column itself does not depend on the values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for BalusC's suggestion, but I tried it, it did not work. It may be other reasons result in. I fixed BalusC's code a little, it works now:

```
table.locations.empty tbody td {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can propose an enhancement to existing answers.

Comment: It will fail when there's a stronger CSS selector which specifies the border. That part is not related to JSF, but just to basic CSS.