# How do I just display a table header if a jsf datatable is empty?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I encounter a problem as the following picture shows:

[please click me to see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIOy.jpg)

The code is as the following, here more than a header line when `#{userData.basicInfoList}` is empty:

```
<h:dataTable id="userData" value="#{userData.basicInfoList}" var="info"
border="1" width="100%" style="margin-top: 10px"
headerClass="headerStyle"
columnClasses="user-id, user-name, user-age, user-sex, user-address, user-phone-no">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="id" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.id}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.name}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="age" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.age}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="sex" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.sex}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="address" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.address}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="phone no" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{info.phoneNo}" />
</h:column>
```

Rendered html as follows:

```
<table id="heForm:userData" border="1" style="margin-top: 10px"
width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">id</th>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">name</th>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">age</th>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">sex</th>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">address</th>
        <th class="headerStyle" scope="col">phone no</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Right click the blank cell and click the "Inspect element" option from the submenu and inspect what element is being rendered in the blank cell.

Comment: Hi, render html was added. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution as follows:

```
<h:dataTable ... styleClass="#{empty userData.basicInfoList ? 'empty' : ''}">
```

Separate style:

```
.empty tbody td{
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: If you improve the other question, flag this one as a duplicate (or remove it)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of h:dataTable

This is a duplicate of

[See @Balusc answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713252/jsf-hdatatable-creates-single-empty-cell-when-no-records)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It help me resolve the problem. And I fixed BalusC's code a little, It works now!

Comment: If u can mark my answer as valid and upvote, I will really appreciate it

Comment: Sure, and please help me upvote my improved solution, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, my reputation is not enough to vote.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, mark it as such (see the flag option) No need to add it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry am a newbie. The flag options shows 1. Spam etc 2. Rude behavior 3. Moderator action. I don't see one for duplicate. May be I don't have enough reputation to see more options?